# php date_create_from_format returning incorrect time

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to take a date that is provided by an external system and convert it to a DateTime for use in mine. However, I am running into issues with the date_create_from_format function that is causing the wrong information to appear.

I am receiving a date and time as a string from another function (that I have confirmed is correct when I call it directly). That string is used to construct a DateTime object using a format string that matches the one called to format the string before it is returned to me. However, the resulting DateTime object is a full 12 hours off. The example code is as follows:

```
var_dump($object->getEndTime());
//string(19) "2017-04-04 18:26 PM" 
//formatted in another function by 
//$endTime = date('Y-m-d G:i A', $endTime);
//return $endTime;

$endTime = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d G:i A', $object->getEndTime());
var_dump($endTime);
//object(DateTime)#150 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2017-04-05 06:26:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" }
```

As demonstrated, it appears the date_create_from_format function is taking my hours value and moving it forward to match a 12-hour time, despite the matching formats, and then not providing an AM/PM value. Is there something I'm missing regarding this function?

Comment: And timezones are the same?

Comment: Think the issue might be that `18:26 PM` isn't right. That should be `6:26 PM`. When using AM/PM, the hours only range from 0-12.

Comment: @Qirel I actually was able to resolve the issue by changing the format, but if I print it ($endTime->format('Y-m-d G:i A')) it still shows the PM. I don't see why it should change the time to match if the string has the PM value and a 24-hour formatted time that would match a PM timestamp.

Comment: That's because the `A` format *is* AM/PM. So if you have that in your new format, of course it'll be there - you told it to be there ;-)

Comment: The result is correct: 18 hours past midday is 6 in the morning the next day :> AM/PM (`A`) only makes sense with a 12-hour format (`g` or `h`).

Comment: You shouldn't use 'G' with 'A'.  G is a 24 hour format and A is a 12 hour format item. use 'g' instead (I recommend 'h' as that is leading zero)